# onbeforeprint and onafterprint is not working in Chrome and IE?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using printing in my project (Using HTML and javascript). In mozilla onbeforeprint and onafterprint is working properly but not working in chrome.

Comment: Chrome [doesn't seem to have support for these events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeprint#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @pimvdb So how can i acheive these events in chrome. Is there any equivalent event for chrome.

Answer (score 11):

What works for Chrome is to check for 'matchmedia' in 'window' as in:

```
                if ('matchMedia' in window) {
                    window.matchMedia('print').addListener(function (media) {
                    //do before-printing stuff
                    });
                } else {
                    window.onbeforeprint = function () {
                    //do before-printing stuff
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The listener seems to get triggered twice when the document is printed (using addListener). The media argument seems to not be very different in those two calls, except for timestamp...

Comment: media.matches will be `true` before printing, and false afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

This works as of Chrome 63, according to their changelog.

Answer (score 2):

Quick update, because support of printing events [has improved a lot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint#Browser_compatibility)

- Chrome 63, releases in December 2017, supports it [source](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5700595042222080)
- Opera 50 as well
- Edge supports it since the beginning
- even old version 6 of IE (6!!) supports it

Answer (score 1):

[Chrome doesn't have onbeforeprint.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeprint.asp)

The preferred method for doing this is to use [print media specific stylesheets](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml).

If you absolutely have to detect [Print operations with javascript cross browser](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) this looks promising, but I haven't tried it myself.

**UPDATE 2021:** it works since [chrome version 63](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint#browser_compatibility)

Comment: this saved my life, thanks Ryan.
I was using @media print { ... } for page print, but somehow the css was being ignored, so I have to through the js way. this worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't support those events. Instead it supports '[window.matchMedia](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_matchmedia.asp)'. Also there is a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571070) that prevents it to print all the pages. For this reason, I suggest you add a print button to your web page and ask users to use the button instead of printing via the Chrome menu.

```
var beforePrint = function() {
    console.log("before");
};
var afterPrint = function() {
    console.log("after");
};

var launchedFromMenu = true;
if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            if(launchedFromMenu) {
                // https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571070
                alert("There is a bug in Chrome/Opera and printing via the main menu does not work properly. Please use the 'print' icon on the page.");
            }
            beforePrint();
        } else {
            afterPrint();
        }
    });
}

// These are for Firefox
window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;

function printPage() {
    window["beforePrint"]();
    launchedFromMenu = false;
    window.print();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome doesn't work onbeforeprint & onAfterPrint.

But you can restrict print page by using css print media

Example

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />`

This css is include in header of the page.

The css having following styles

```
#header, #menu, #entry-content, .noprint {display: none;}
```