# What is the cross-browser approach to bind to beforeprint and afterprint with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I need to bind to `beforeprint` and `afterprint` events to write some stat. But unfortunately with jQuery the following code does't work in all modern browsers:

```
$(window).on('beforeprint', function () { 
   console.log('beforeprint')
});

$(window).on('afterprint', function () {
   console.log('afterprint')
});
```

Are there any strong jquery plugin or pattern to cross browser binding to `beforeprint` and `afterprint` events in 2016 year?

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22971832/2734369 unsure about any plugins, but i think the chances of slim of finding a plugin supporting a deprecated event

Comment: Ok, what is the best way to detect opening of browser's print dialog?

Comment: jQuery is supposed be your cross browser bridge & guarantee, because that's the only reason it exists. However, you cannot expect jQuery to give you the means of commandeering things on browsers with no alternatives or no support at all.

Comment: Ok, what is the best way to detect opening of browser's print dialog in pure JavaScript without jQuery?